# Properties of a mapping between two differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes, steady-state

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a nonsingular matrix, $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function. Consider the following differential equation
$$\tag{$\ast$}\label{ast}
\dot{x}(t)=-x(t)+f(Ax(t)+b),\ \ x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where, for a vector $x$, $f(x)$ acts component-wise on the entries of $x$, i.e. $[f(x)]_i=f(x_i)$.

Using the change of variable $y(t):=Ax(t)+b$, it seems to me that above differential equation can be equivalently rewritten as
$$\tag{$\ast\ast$}\label{astast}
\dot{y}(t)=-y(t)+Af(y(t))+b,\ \ y(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

> **My questions:**
>
> 1. Is it true that \eqref{ast} admits a **unique** equilibrium (i.e., a unique $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\bar{x}=f(A\bar{x}+b)$) if and only if  \eqref{astast} admits a **unique** equilibrium?
> 2. (*In case the answer to question 1 is in the affirmative*) Is it true that \eqref{ast} admits a **unique locally stable** equilibrium if and only if  \eqref{astast} admits a **unique locally stable** equilibrium?

Comment: It looks like a special case of [smooth equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy#Smooth_and_orbital_equivalence).

Comment: @user539887: thanks! So it seems to me that if $f$ is smooth then both answers should be in the affirmative. However, do you know if the smoothness assumption can be relaxed?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous only then one need not have unique solvability. But an affine change of coordinates (and this is, in fact, the above transformation) preserves **almost** everything interesting even then (except angles between orbits, for example).

Comment: @user539887: Thank you. So, assuming for instance that $f$ is piecewise continuous, both answers to questions 1 and 2 are in the affirmative since I'm considering an affine change of coordinates?

Comment: Yes, everything should be O.K. (perhaps there can be some difficulty in existence/uniqueness when $f$ is only piecewise continuous).